# Backbone Model url options overrides the url param

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Define a Backbone.Model

```js
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

Instantiate the model with an url **as an option**

```js
var myInstance = new MyModel({}, {url: 'test'});
console.log(myInstance.url);  // prints "test"
```

Is this something expected?

Comment: Your setup outputs a function, not `test`, as far as I can tell http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/8GfLJ/

Comment: @nikoshr good catch!, this is happening on VERSION=1.0.0. Update: http://jsfiddle.net/8GfLJ/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was deprecated in [Backbone 1.1.0](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog) :

> Backbone Models no longer attach `url` and `urlRoot` options, but you can do it yourself if you prefer.